# Need help in OnChange event Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have five text fields which are mark1, mark2, mark3, mark4 and total. I have a problem to make the total automatically display in the text field. I have no problem with the calculation part. But I can't make the total to be display automatically in the text field. How can I make the total to be automatically display in the textfield once the user have finish entered all the four marks? I know it have to do with the OnChange event using Javascript. But I did not get the right codes. Does anyone can help me with this? Really need your advise.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide some code samples?

Answer (score 4):

Daisy, something like this should work. You can [view a live demo](http://jsbin.com/uyifa) of this code on JSBin.

```
<input type="text" name="mark1" id="mark1" value="" />
<input type="text" name="mark2" id="mark2" value="" />
<input type="text" name="mark3" id="mark3" value="" />
<input type="text" name="mark4" id="mark4" value="" />
<input type="text" name="total" id="total" value="" />

<!-- Script block must come AFTER the input elements -->

<script type="text/javascript">
  var m1    = document.getElementById('mark1'),
      m2    = document.getElementById('mark2'),
      m3    = document.getElementById('mark3'),
      m4    = document.getElementById('mark4'),
      total = document.getElementById('total');

  function calculate_total(){
    // Use your real calculation here
    total.value = Number(m1.value) + Number(m2.value) + Number(m3.value) + Number(m4.value);
  }

  if( window.addEventListener ) {
    m1.addEventListener('change', calculate_total, false);
    m2.addEventListener('change', calculate_total, false);
    m3.addEventListener('change', calculate_total, false);
    m4.addEventListener('change', calculate_total, false);
  } else if(window.attachEvent){
    m1.attachEvent('onchange', calculate_total);
    m2.attachEvent('onchange', calculate_total);
    m3.attachEvent('onchange', calculate_total);
    m4.attachEvent('onchange', calculate_total);
  }
</script>
```

**UPDATE:** Since you want a letter grade entered (A, B, C, F, etc) I would recommend a `select` control instead of an `input[type='text']`. One of the grade fields would look like this:

```
<select name="mark1" id="mark1">
    <option value="">Select Grade</option>
    <option value="100">A</option>
    <option value="90">B</option>
    <option value="80">C</option>
    <option value="70">D</option>
    <option value="50">F</option>
</select>
```

You put the number value in the `value=` portion, but you can display the friendlier A, B, C, etc.

And anywhere there was `.value` replace with `.selectedValue` (Except `total.value` of course).

Comment: Thanks for the codes. But I do have some problems here because user only will enter the grade. From the grade the system will count the marks. For example, if user entered A then the mark is 100 and if B the mark is 70. How can I do that? Any idea?

Comment: Always test for standard methods **before** proprietary ones (`attachEvent` vs. `addEventListener` in this case). Also, don't assume that `addEventListener` exists if `attachEvent` doesn't.

Comment: @kangax Good points. I guess I always thought it was opposite (use proprietary first), but that makes total sense... don't know why it didn't occur to me earlier. Answer updated to reflect both comments.Thanks! Would you use a third setter like `m1.onchange = function(){ ... }` in the `else` statement if both tests failed?

Answer (score 2):

Daisy, [Doug provided a great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036155/need-help-in-onchange-event-javascript/2036207#2036207), but after reading your comment I thought I would contribute a small change. Note the `grades` array of values and the small change to Doug's function:

```
// Add grades and corresponding value below
var grades = {A:100,B:70};

function calculate_total(){
  // Use your real calculation here
  total.value = grades[m1.value] + grades[m2.value] + grades[m3.value] + grades[m4.value];
}
```