# OnChange .attachEvent Listener Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to fire off an `AJAX` `GET` request when a text field changes, but I am having trouble getting the `OnChange Listener` to work, if anyone could shed some light onto why its not working I would much appreciate it.

```
document.getElementById('address1').attachEvent("OnChange", loadXMLDoc);
function loadXMLDoc()
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://myurl.co.uk/AddressFinder/UpdateControler.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: The event is all lowercase `"onchange"`.   And, `attachEvent()` only works in IE.  And, the `onchange` event only fires when the field loses focus, not everytime the value of the field changes.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036155/need-help-in-onchange-event-javascript

Comment: As said by @jfriend00, `.attachEvent` is for IE (less than 8), other browsers would use `.addEventListener('change', loadXMLDoc, false);`

Answer (score 1):

```
if(window.addEventListener) {
    document.getElementById('address1').addEventListener("change", loadXMLDoc);
} else if (window.attachEvent){
    document.getElementById('address1').attachEvent("onchange", loadXMLDoc);
}

function loadXMLDoc(){
   alert('worked');   
}
```